# Unable to parse registry.pol using LGPO.exe

Tags: windows, command-line, group-policy

I am currently trying to parse a registry.pol using the LGPO.exe. I have used the instructions based on https://brookspeppin.com/2018/11/04/how-to-individually-modify-and-deploy-local-gpo-settings-lgpo/ 
The first step requires me to backup the registry.pol using the keyword "Backup" with this command:

```
lgpo.exe /b C:\Temp /n “Backup”
```

This allows the user to specify the term "Backup" instead of typing out the GUID in the next step. However when executing the second command to parse the registry.pol to a text file using the command:

```
LGPO.exe /parse /m C:\Temp\LGPO_Backup\DomainSysvol\GPO\Machine\registry.pol >> C:\Templgpo.txt
```

I have gotten an error: 
Cannot open input file `"C:\Temp\LGPO_Backup\DomainSysvol\GPO\Machine\registry.pol"`

Anyone with experience with LGPO.exe, I hope you could provide some assistance to this error as it is crucial that I used the keyword instead of the actual GUID as I am automating this process through multiple servers and it would be easier to do it with a common keyword.

Edit:
The registry.pol exist, so there shouldn't be an issue regarding the file not existing. Regarding file permissions, the command prompt was run with the run with administrator option.

Edit 2:
Not really a solution to this but if anyone is trying to automate using Ansible to parse registry.pol, you can try directly parsing from the registry.pol file instead of using a backup, this removes the need to use the keyword to convert the .txt file back to .pol

Answer (score 0):

Please try putting your path in quotes:

LGPO.exe /parse /m "C:\Temp\LGPO_Backup\DomainSysvol\GPO\Machine\registry.pol" >> C:\Templgpo.txt

Answer (score 0):

I found your question while getting the same error trying to automate GPO edits as part of an AWS ec2 image builder pipeline for Microsoft Windows Server 2019 AMIs. After much struggle, I finally arrived at a solution and hope it helps others as this is an old post!

This solution worked locally, however for use in aws ec2 image builder or other pipeline you may need to figure out the correct directory in that particular environment. AWS produces something like this for storing the powershell commands as a single script:

ExecutePowerShell: Created temporary directory: C:\Windows\TEMP\AWSTOE039567397

First, I stored the path to registry.pol as variable $registry with a wildcard for the GUID(not using the backup method) using Get-ChildItem.

`$registry = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\\Temp\\MS-L1\\*\\DomainSysvol\\GPO\\Machine\\registry.pol`

Next, use LGPO Utility's parse command with the newly created variable containing path to registry.pol

`C:\Temp\LGPO.exe /parse /m $registry >> C:\Temp\MS-L1.txt`

[Command Line Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnxzi.png)